# How to download Twitter Direct Messages

Tags: twitter, twitter-direct-message, twitter-archive

I am trying to figure out how to download old Twitter DM's from the past few months.

I did a Contaxio sync but the CSV file does not seem to contain any DM's at all.

I tried to build a Twitter app but got stuck not know how to run "twit-backup.pl --generate-session"

Answer (score 3):

I have created a [tool](https://github.com/Mincka/DMArchiver) (https://github.com/Mincka/DMArchiver) to download my direct messages, with the ability to also download the uploaded images and GIFs (as MP4).

Because it does not rely on the API, it is possible to download more than 200 messages. The script just simulate the "scrolling" you can do manually in a conversation or on your phone.

The main idea is to make requests in loop by calling the following URL with a valid `auth_token` cookie value for the authentication and parse the json response:
https://twitter.com/messages/with/conversation?id=1337&max_entry_id=1337

The `max_entry_id` value is not required for the first request. You need to use the value of the `min_entry_id` variable in the response as the new `max_entry_id` in each subsequent iteration to get the next 20 older tweets. When `max_entry_id` is not in the json response, you are at the begin of the thread.